# Right Rotation Linked List Recursively

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, rotation

I need to create a method to rotate or shift elements in a `LinkedList` which is called `ListItem` for my program to the right recursively. For example, I have the List `1->2->3->4` after the method it is `4->1->2->3`. The Method should return the rotated List.

So, this is what could be helpful for the method:

```
public class ListItem<T>
{

    public T key;
    public ListItem<T> next;

    /**
     * Constructor of this Class
     * 
     * @param key
     *            the key of the ListItemAbstract
     */
    public ListItem(T key)
    {
        this.key = key;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass())
            return false;
        if (this.key == null && ((ListItem<T>) obj).key == null)
            return true;
        if (this.key != null && this.key.equals(((ListItem<T>) obj).key))
        {
            if (this.next == null)
                if (((ListItem<T>) obj).next == null)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            return this.next.equals(((ListItem<T>) obj).next);
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    /**
     * This methode returns the Element on the given position.
     * 
     * @param pos
     *            the position to return the key from. Position 1 means the current element
     * @return the key of the element at pos
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if the position ist not in the list
     */
    public T get(int pos) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        // recursion stop
        if (pos == 1)
        {
            return this.key;
        }
        else if (pos > 1)
        {
            // recursion start: call this method again for the next element of the list,
            // but check for NullpointerException first
            if (next != null)
            {
                return next.get(pos - 1);
            }
            else
            {
                //
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("the index is greater than the number of elements in this list");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("the position is less than 1, but must be equal to or higher than 1");
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the size of the List
     * 
     * @return the size of this list
     */
    public int getSize()
    {
        if (this.key == null && this.next == null)
        {
            // recursion stop: no next element and this key is null -> don't add it to the size
            return 0;
        }
        else if (this.next == null) // deleting this if-case causes a NullpointerException
        {
            // recursion stop: no next element, but this key is not null -> add it to the size
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            // recursion start: recall this method for the next element and increase the size by one
            return this.next.getSize() + 1;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Inserts an key into this list.
     * 
     * @param key
     *            the key to insert.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if key is null
     */
    public void insert(T key) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        if (key == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot insert null");
        }
        else if (this.key == null && this.next == null)
        {
            this.key = key;
        }
        else
        {
            ListItem<T> p = this;
            while (p.next != null)
            {
                p = p.next;
            }
            p.next = new ListItem<T>(key);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far for the method:

```
/**
     * The method shifts the elements of the List to the right.
     * 
     * @param lst
     *            the list to work on
     * @return the new list
     */
    public ListItem<T> ringShiftRight(ListItem<T> lst) {
        if (lst == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (lst.next == null) {
            return lst;
        } 
        // TODO Here I have no Idea how to create the method any further 
    }
```

Comment: you remove the last item and insert the removed item at the beginning. I don't see you trying that anywhere...

Comment: I can't believe, that you can make it recursively. The method needs to rotate only one time. I had the same idea with removing the last item etc. but it didn't seem to work with the given condition, that the task should be solved recursively.

Comment: You use recursion to locate the second-last node, i.e. the node referencing the last node, so it can be put first, and so it can be removed by null'ing out the `next` reference on that second-last node. Sure, a loop would be better (no stack overflow), but I assume this is an exercise in recursion, i.e. a learning experience.

Answer (score -2):

Traverse ListItem till last item and that will become ListItem to be returned. Add input `lst`to next of next.

```
    ListItem<T> returnList = this.ringShiftRight(lst.next);
    lst.next.next = lst;
    lst.next = null;
    return returnList;
```

Comment: This is not a recursive implementation, as question says is required, and it's about the worst version ever, both performance-wise and memory-wise. Cloning all the nodes of the list just to move the last node up front? Really?